# Plot Function in Java

Tags: java, graph, plot, graphics2d

I am writing a program to plot [x(t),y(t)] with variable t in a certain range (input by users). So far, I have created 3 vectors to hold values of t, x(t) and y(t). My current approach is to create vectors of points  (around 1000 points), then draw a line (or path) between two adjacent points in the vector. However, the result is not as what I expected.

The full format of from the users:

```
Plot [x(t),y(t)] x=a..b y=a..b t=a..b where a,b are the range of x,y,t
```

For instance, the user can input functions:

```
x(t) = 5*sin(3t + 5), t=-19..19
y(t) = 4*cos(2t), t=-19.19
```

Here is my code for drawing:

```
public static void drawGraph(String sf, String sx, String sy, String st) {
  JFrame mygraph = new JFrame("PlotGraph v0.1");

  final Vector<Double> range_t = getRangeT(st); //get the range of t
  //create a corresponding vectors of x and y based on values of t
  final Vector<Double> range_x = getRangeX(range_t,funcX,var);
  final Vector<Double> range_y = getRangeY(range_t,funcY,var);

  //draw the graph to a JPanel, our graph is actually just a collection of points connecting 2 points
  mygraph.add(new JPanel() {


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2.setColor(Color.BLUE );
          g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
          GeneralPath gpx = new GeneralPath();
          GeneralPath gpy = new GeneralPath();
          for (int i=0; i<998; i++) {
            gpy.moveTo(range_t.get(i),range_y.get(i));
                  gpy.curveTo(range_t.get(i),range_y.get(i),range_t.get(i+1),range_y.get(i+1),range_t.get(i+2),range_y.get(i+2));
            gpx.moveTo(range_t.get(i),range_x.get(i));
            gpx.curveTo(range_t.get(i),range_x.get(i),range_t.get(i+1),range_x.get(i+1),range_t.get(i+2),range_x.get(i+2));

            //g2.draw(lineY);
            g2.draw(gpx);
            g2.draw(gpy);
          }
          g2.dispose(); 
        }
      });

  mygraph.setBounds(125,25,650,600);
  mygraph.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  mygraph.setDefaultCloseOperation(mygraph.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  mygraph.setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is what I get for 2 functions above:
[image]

**QUESTION:** **Is there any way I can make the plot better (scale it up)?!**

Comment: I think you will get better results (answers) if you tag your question "java"

Comment: What are the bounds set on your drawing component?

Comment: Also, could you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: That code formatting was killing me.

Comment: Sorry guys, I copied pasted it from my editor :(

Comment: Fixed the format! I hate the editor from SO

Comment: The bounds of the drawing will be determined from the users as in my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're graphing the parametric equations wrong.

For parametric equations, you should iterate over `t` from t<sub>min</sub> to t<sub>max</sub>. At each value, evaluate x(t) and y(t), and plot a point there - at (x(t), y(t)).

It looks like you're plotting points at (t, y(t)), etc. You'll need a helper function to *evaluate* the user-input function for each variable, for example:

```
public double evaluateX(double t) { ... }
public double evaluateY(double t) { ... }
```

In those functions, you'll have to parse the user's text into code (tokenize, maybe?) and then evaluate it.

Then, you can have a loop as such:

```
GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
double tstep = (tmax - tmin) / 998;
for (double t=tmin; t += tstep; t<tmax) {
    double x = evaluateX(t);
    double y = evaluateY(t);
    if (t == 0) {
        gp.moveTo(x, y);
    } else {
        gp.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}
g2d.draw(gp);
```

From there, a scale factor should be easy to implement. Try something like this:

```
GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
final double scale = 3.0;
double tstep = (tmax - tmin) / 998;
for (double t=tmin; t += tstep; t<tmax) {
    double x = scale * evaluateX(t);
    double y = scale * evaluateY(t);
    if (t == 0) {
        gp.moveTo(x, y);
    } else {
        gp.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}
g2d.draw(gp);
```

Comment: Ya I have done with the parser and can evaluate the input from the users. The full format of input will be:
Plot [x(t),y(t)] x=a..b y=a..b t=a..b
where a,b are the range of x,y,t

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I may stick with the scale for now. Also how can we position the graphs? i.e I want to draw coordinator x-axis, y-axis with the origin 0 at the center of the JFrame. Then have my graphs drawn at the center too. For now graphs are drawn the top left corner which does not look good!!

Comment: Basically, you're translating from the *equation* coordinate space to the *Swing* coordinate space. In the equation space, up is +Y and right is +X. But in Swing, up is -Y and right is +X. So you'll probably have something like `y = -(scale * evaluateY(t) + offsetY)`, and `x = scale * evaluateX(t) + offsetX`. This really all depends on your graph window.